# Wait for Magento CE 2.0?

Tags: upgrade, magento-community, version

we are planning to get help building a Magento Community Edition store. It's quite a big investment for our company.

Should we wait until 2.0 is released or will we do fine with the 1.9.1.1-version? Is it hard do upgrade from 1.9.1.1 to 2.0 and is it worth it?

Comment: forget about Magento 2.0 for next two years...

Comment: Good article by [Andreas von Studnitz](https://twitter.com/avstudnitz): https://www.integer-net.com/right-moment-for-magento-2/

Answer (score 3):

Simply take a look at the magento2 [repository on github](https://github.com/magento/magento2). Structure has changed, new patterns where implemented, so it is quite hard to simply "upgrade" from version 1.9.x to 2.x.

By now there are many magento v1.4.x - latest version shops online. So the more important question is, in my honest opinion, when do you like to go live?

I would not build a new Shop based on magento 2.0 yet. It is ok to build it up based on 1.9.x, because the eCommerce lifecycle normally takes around 2-4 years until you completly relaunch the webshop. Until then the magento 2.0 should be released and most of the bugs shipping with a new version should be fixed.

But in the end, it is your choice.

Comment: We would like to go live this fall, but since we have a working platform today (not Magento), we could wait if 2.0 is worth waiting for.

Comment: With Magento 2.0 slated for a stable Q4 release this year, you would not be wise to attempt to launch using a beta-state release for this fall. Also consider the availability of talent to develop a Magento 2 shop this year. Your resources would be limited. I think Magento will be giving something like a 5 year support lifespan for Magento 1 after M2 is live. Personally I wouldn't see a good reason to shift to M2 this year, but then again we do need some early adopters.

Answer (score 3):

Magento 2 is considered a "replatform", so there is nothing like an *update* from 1.x to 2.0. However, there is a *migration* guide: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html

So if you start with 1.9 now and consider moving to Magento 2, plan with 2x the work. I would still recommend to build a store on 1.9 *now*, if your client is not an "early adopter" type, willing to take a huge risk. There will be not many extensions available when 2.0 merchant beta gets released in Q3/2015, less knowledge resources and there still might be lots of bugs.

Magento 1 still gets active support for 3 years and there are community efforts to take over long term support after that because there will be lots of stores running on Magento 1 for years, so I consider it a safe bet.

Answer (score 1):

if you need some extensions, than you have to go for 1.9.1 or if you have good devolopment team, than you don't need to worry about extensions for 1.9.1